# How to Transfer a folder from AWS EC2 to AWS S3 through php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I want to upload a zip file and unzip it in AWS S3 but I got to know that to achieve this I have to upload zip file in AWS EC2 and unzip it their and then transfer it to AWS S3.
I am done with uploading and unzipping the folder in AWS EC2 through php but stuck in transfer that unzipped folder to AWS S3 from AWS EC2 through php.
I think this is issue of permission to that folder, I am not sure about this and I am using this code to transfer folder from EC2 to S3

```
if($s3->putObjectFile($path_in_S3, $bucket , $path_in_EC2, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ) ){
     $msg = "S3 Upload Successful.";       
}else {
     $msg = "Error";
}
```

Above code is properly working with files but not working with folder
Please help me out on this, any help or suggestion would be appreciated ,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Easiest: mount the s3 bucket locally http://stackoverflow.com/a/24102890/267540

Comment: Here is the official example for copying a folder to S3 using PHP: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-transfer.html

Comment: Thanks e4c5 and Mark B for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: Dear Mark B, I am very new in AWS so please don't mind if I ask you some stupid question. I have referred that doc but i got confuse what to place in region and version while creating a new object of S3Client, I have checked out region in my S3 bucket but its shows "S3 does not require region selection." and also not getting version. please suggest me on this