# Retrieve files from S3 and put them in to EC2 Linux instance using Java

Tags: java, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Here are the different ways that I can think of but not sure which is the best way :

1. Create a console app in Java using [GetObject](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples/s3/objects.html) provided in [AWS Java SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/).
2. Use [s3 sync](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html).
3. Use SNS>Lambda.
4. Use [REST API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html).
5. Use SNS>HTTPS [(Java Servlet)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.example.java.html).

Performance is important as I may have to pull many files of varing sizes down to the linux instance.

The problem I see with option 1 is that I would need to have some kind of polling behavior in place.

With option 2 I don't know (a) if I neeed to run this command periodically or if it keeps running syncing files forever (b) if it just runs once how do I wrap it in a java program? Also I'm new to Java and Linux. If this was .Net and Windows I would create a windows service but not sure what's the Java/Linux equivalent.

Option 3 is not on the table as Lambda is ruled out (long story).

So which is a good way to do this as far as performance, maintainability and scalability goes? The number of S3 buckets I will need to monitor will vary (increase) as will the frequency/size of the files.

Thanks

Comment: *The problem I see with option 1 is that I would need to have some kind of polling behavior in place.* - why is this a problem?  cron? or a java solution?

Comment: Could you please describe your requirements more clearly? For example, are you saying that you need to replicate data from S3 to EC2 immediately, or is a regular batch acceptable? Oh, and `aws s3 sync` is one-off, not continuous -- you'd have to run it on a regular schedule to copy new files.

Comment: @Scary Wombat : It's not a problem but just something I have to handle. I was thinking that I would have to keep track of processed files but I could also move them to a processed bucket after copying them to the linux instance. If that's the option you suggest are there any tips on what to avoid, or any sample code that does the polling? Not very familiar with Java and Linux so any help is appreciated.

Comment: @ John Rotenstein : The requirements allow for a small delay (less than 15 mins) between a file being dropped in the S3 bucket and it being copied to the linux instance. As far as the frequency and the size of files, they will vary and the solution should be able to scale with the requirements. However I implement the requirement, the process will need to be reliable, survive a reboot, and easy to maintain like say a windows service. Thanks for the s3 sync insight. What option would you choose? More details and tips the better. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use Lambda Function to copy the file from S3 Bucket to EC2 via SSH.
Trigger: S3 Object Creation

Check this Link: https://privatedock.wordpress.com/2017/08/21/s3-bucket-ec2-directory-sync-using-lambda/

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

just curious -- you said you're not familiar with Java and/or Linux, but you need to solve the problem. would using Python instead of java be an option? in my experience, it's simpler and faster to get a python project with external package dependencies off the ground than it is for java.

you could use a hybrid of the solutions you and others listed above: 
1. cron job that invokes a python script
2. python script uses 's3 sync' to sync data down
3. either another s3 call to move sync'd file to another bucket (or folder) or rename those files in-place to mark them as 'processed'

it's a good start that can always be 'hardened' with more logic to make foolproof. i would suggest trying something like i listed above (with Python) and use a test bucket or two to prototype your ideas. you could have an answer within hours if you stick to a fast 'polling' schedule on the order of minutes. HTH

Comment: Thanks. I was just looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102666/local-access-to-amazon-s3-bucket-from-ec2-instance?rq=1 and I see that s3fs-fuse and boto are options as well. We're .net developers asked to use java, so while I know python I don't think it's going to be a viable option as no one else in the team will be able to support it.